# What is the maximum size that a .msi windows installer file can be?

Tags: files

We are doing some upload testing to the server, specifically taking in .msi package installer files. None of my googling has shown me a definitive answer, but I need to test the max file size that can be uploaded, which seems to be restricted by the max .msi file size. Anyone know?

Comment: How long is a piece of string...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Windows Installer blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20151030124006/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2005/09/18/461810.aspx):

> Multi-part CABs can get the total size of a set of files past 2GB, possibly to 64K * 2GB

64K * 2GB is 128TB.

I expect the maximum file size you can upload will be dictated by something else - e.g. the amount of storage on the server or some kind of upload quota.

Comment: Part of me says this blog is from 7 years ago - is it still accurate? The other part of me says I'll worry about that when I hit a 128TB installer...

Comment: Yes this is still accurate. However, note that this implies that external files (the .cabs) need to be included in the directory. Therefore, in one single .msi file, the largest it can be is 2GB.